# Custom post query with multiple fields with number values. Totalisation needed

Tags: php, wordpress, calculation

The following code gives me several tables (sorted by category) with custom fields and number values. A special case is the column 'Kranz' if it is Ja (yes) it should add 1 to the result.

What I need now, is a totalisation at the end of every table and then another totalisation for all the tables. How can I do that?

Thanks!

```
<div class="togglecontent"> 
<?php
$portraetrangliste = get_the_id();

$catargs = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'jahr',
        'order' => 'DESC',
);
$cats = get_categories($catargs);

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'rangliste',
        'meta_key'      => 'portrait_nid',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_value'    =>  $portraetrangliste,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'jahr',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $cat->cat_ID,
            ),
        ),
);
global $post;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ): 
?> 
<h5>Saison <?php echo $cat->cat_name ; ?> </h5>
  <table class="portraetrangliste">
    <tr>
      <th>Rang</th>
      <th>Kranz</th>
      <th>Sieger</th>
      <th>Jahreswertung<br />Punkte</th>
      <th>Bezwungene <br /> Eidgenossen </th>
      <th>Datum / Fest</th>
    </tr> 
<?php
while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); 
?> 
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong> <?php the_field( 'rang' ); ?> </strong>
      </td>
      <td> <?php if ( get_field( 'kranzgewinn' ) == 1 ) : ?> <?php echo 'Ja'; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php echo 'Nein'; ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
      <td> <?php if ( get_field( 'sieger' ) == 1 ) : ?> <?php echo 'Ja'; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php echo 'Nein'; ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
      <td> <?php the_field( 'punkte_jahresliste' ); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php the_field( 'bezwungene_eidgenossen' ); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php global $post; ?> <?php $fest_nid = get_field( 'fest_nid' ); ?> <?php if ( $fest_nid) : ?> <?php $post = $fest_nid; ?> <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?> <?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?> - <a href="
                    
                    
                    <?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
    </tr> <?php
   endwhile; ?>
  </table> 
 <?php endif; 

// Added this now 
wp_reset_query() ; 
}
?></div>
```

Result should be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straight forward, for the Kranz column that's a counter variable that you increment whenever that column is set to Ja. The other two are totals that you add to whenever you display the column, and you need two sets of these, one in the category loop, and the other in the post loop. Something like:

```
<?php $global_total_kranz = 0;
$global_total_jp = 0;
$global_total_be = 0;

foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
  $cat_total_kranz = 0;
  $cat_total_jp = 0;
  $cat_total_be = 0;

  if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      if( get_field( 'kranzgewinn' ) == 1 ) {
        echo 'Ja';
        $cat_total_kranz++;
      }
      $cat_total_jp = $cat_total_jp + get_field( 'punkte_jahresliste' );
      $cat_total_be = $cat_total_be + get_field( 'bezwungene_eidgenossen');
    }

    $global_total_kranz = $global_total_kranz + $cat_total_kranz;
    $global_total_jp = $global_total_jp + $cat_total_jp;
    $global_total_be = $global_total_be + $cat_total_be;
  }
}
```

The global counters (although forgive me for calling them global, they are not PHP global variables, that is just the terminology I have used) are set to 0 to begin with, and then in each category we create category specific counters. The category specific counters are incremented on in our post loop, and then after each post loop in each category we take the category counters and add those values to the global counters.

This should be a good start to get you closer to what you're trying to achieve.